# css and js not found in magento 2.3.5

Tags: composer, requirejs, magento2.3.5-p1, mixins, windows10

Refused to apply style from

> http://localhost/magento2-2.3.5-p1/pub/static/version1593595791/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css

---

because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: frontend loaded successfully or not?

Comment: Some icons are missing..but loaded the front end.

Comment: Magento installed fresh?

Comment: Yes.I have installed the fresh magento.Admin is unable to load.

Comment: please check my aswer

Comment: @SonaliGhule For Magento 2 better you can use Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step -1
Go To Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php**

replace **isPathInDirectories()** Method

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Step -2 Run command**

```
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: It works..Thank You for the help.

Comment: welcome @SonaliGhule

Comment: @RasikMiyani to simplify the solution you can use my composer package, which solve the issue - https://packagist.org/packages/idealcode/magento2-windows-compatibility, install as `composer require idealcode/magento2-windows-compatibility`